# Convert.ToDateTime In C# From Specific Date String

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I have a specific date `string`: `"13/02/07,16:05:13+00"`

I am trying to convert it in `C#` to a `datetime` (`Convert.toDateTime`) but I keep receiving errors.

I have also tried to parse it using the following code to no avail:

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yy/MM/dd,hh:mm:ss+00",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

How do I convert a `string` to `datetime` for a really specific `datetime` `string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `CurrentCulture` - use the invariant culture. Otherwise you'll be picking up the current culture's date and time separators.

Also, you need to use `HH` instead of `hh` as you're using a 24-hour clock, not a 12-hour clock. This works fine:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string date = "13/02/07,16:05:13+00";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yy/MM/dd,HH:mm:ss+00",
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
}
```

Is the "+00" definitely always going to be the same? If you need to cope with non-zero offsets, it will change things a bit.

Comment: I'm thinking the +00 might change. is there anywhere just to not consider it at all?

Comment: @MrPink: Well you could trim it yourself first. Or you could take it into account by parsing into a `DateTimeOffset` using the [`zz` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#zzSpecifier).

Answer (score 0):

Use `HH` for the hour component when using military time.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("13/02/07,16:05:13+00", "yy/MM/dd,HH:mm:ss+00",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```